# Bob win conditions with Machine Gun

Tags: shadow-hunters

So if bob uses his ability of hitting 2 damage with machine gun equipped, would it be counted as his win if he rolled a 2 damage to 2 people holding equipment with 3 on his own and dying from the machine gun?

Comment: Could someone who understands the situation better improve the title of this question to better capture what's being asked?

Comment: A more accurate title would be "Bob win conditions with Machine Gun" and I have suggested it but not sure if it will get approved.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming he chose to use his ability to steal the other players equipment instead of doing damage to them as he would then meet his win condition of having 5 peices of equipment.

He would also win if the damage to the other players was enough to kill them as you gain a piece of equipment from a player when you kill them so in either case Bob would immediately  win the game

From the rule book

Bob Neutral Robbery: If you inflict 2 or more points of damage to another character, you can take an Equipment Card of your choice from that character instead of giving him/her the damage.

As a player takes damage during the game, they move the HP piece onto the number on the board corresponding to how much damage they currently have. HP pieces are used to show the damage levels of all players. A player's character dies when they have accumulated damage equal or more to the HP listed on their character card. When a character dies, the player must flip their character card face up if they have not already and remove their HP piece and Player piece from the board. If a player has killed another player, they are allowed to take one Equipment card from the dead player and discard the rest.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Hunters